# How to generate this JSON object?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with the following values:

`['persona1', 'Persona2', 'Persona3', 'Persona4']`

And I have another array with the names of each person:

`['JUAN', 'CARLOS', 'PEDRO','MATEO']`

I need to generate a JSON object like the following:

`{ persona1: 'JUAN', persona2: 'CARLOS', persona3: 'PEDRO', persona4: 'MATEO' }`

Each value in the first array becomes the key for the corresponding value in the second array.

How can I do this in Javascript?

Comment: Lo siento, pero es un regla de este espacio que las preguntas sean solamente in inglés.

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/#zipObject

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the array and generate the object dynamically.

```js
let arr1 = [ 'foo', 'bar' ]
let arr2 = [ 'baz', 'qux' ]
let obj = {}
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) obj[arr1[i]] = arr2[i];
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Looks like someone downvoted all the answers

Answer (score -1):

You could use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) here

```js
const arr1 = ["persona1", "Persona2", "Persona3", "Persona4"];
const arr2 = ["JUAN", "CARLOS", "PEDRO", "MATEO"];

const result = arr1.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  acc[curr] = arr2[i];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: or even `const result = arr1.reduce((acc, curr, i) => ({...acc, [curr]: arr2[i]}), {});`

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is a combination of `zip`ping two arrays together and then converting the resulting pairs into the key/value entries in an object. As @Phil mentioned in their comment, the `lodash` library has a function to do this called `zipObject`, but if you don't want to load that entire library, it's not hard to create your own with `reduce`. Here's one version (found at https://lowrey.me/lodash-zipobject-in-es6-javascript/):

```
const zipObject = (props, values) => {
  return props.reduce((prev, prop, i) => {
    return Object.assign(prev, { [prop]: values[i] });
  }, {});
};
```

Running it on your data:

```
keys = ['persona1', 'Persona2', 'Persona3', 'Persona4']
nombres = ['JUAN', 'CARLOS', 'PEDRO','MATEO']

zipObject(keys, nombres) 
//=> 
{
  persona1: 'JUAN',
  Persona2: 'CARLOS',
  Persona3: 'PEDRO',
  Persona4: 'MATEO'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create an empty object, loop over the first array, and take each item in the array as the key, and take each item of the second array as the value.
Then you can you the `JSON.stringify()` function to convert that object to JSON string.

```
const arr1 = ['persona1', 'Persona2', 'Persona3', 'Persona4']

const arr2 = ['JUAN', 'CARLOS', 'PEDRO', 'MATEO']

const output = {}

arr1.forEach((item, i) => output[item] = arr2[i])
console.log(JSON.stringify(output))
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const personKeyArr = ['persona1', 'Persona2', 'Persona3', 'Persona4']
const personValArr = ['JUAN', 'CARLOS', 'PEDRO','MATEO']

const retValue = {}
personKeyArr.forEach((x,i)=>retValue[x] = [personValArr[i]])
```

Comment: Add some description to explain your code.